# How to print key and values separately in scala mapValues output?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a output from below scala code

```
    val aryDF = Seq((("g3,g4"),Array(("D2,D3,D1"),("D2,D5,D1")))).toDF("v1","v2")
    addresses.toSeq.flatMap(s => s.split(",")).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Here the output is as below

```
    [D2 -> 2, D5 -> 1, D1 -> 2, D3 -> 1]
```

However I am trying to print it as key and values into and array[String,String] like format as below

```
    [D2, D5, D1, D3][2, 1, 2, 1]
```

I have tried to do it but it gives output as string how to convert as array[string,string].Below is the udf i wrote:

```
    val countAddresses = udf((addresses: Seq[String]) => {
    val mp=addresses.toSeq.flatMap(s =>s.split(",")).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    mp.keySet.mkString("[", ", ", "]") ++ mp.values.mkString("[", ",", "]")})

    val df2 = aryDF.withColumn("output", countAddresses($"v2"))
```

Comment: The form `[D2, D5, D1, D3][2, 1, 2, 1]` doesn't seem line an `array[String,String]`. Do you mean `["D2, D5, D1, D3", "2, 1, 2, 1"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of generating the `ArrayType` column with the concatenated key string and value string as its elements:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val aryDF = Seq(
  ("g3,g4", Array("D2,D3,D1", "D2,D5,D1"))
).toDF("v1", "v2")

val countAddresses = udf( (addresses: Seq[String]) => {
    val mp = addresses.flatMap(_.split(",")).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    Array(mp.keys.mkString("[", ", ", "]"), mp.values.mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
  }
)

val df2 = aryDF.withColumn("output", countAddresses($"v2"))

df2.show(false)
// +-----+--------------------+--------------------------------+
// |v1   |v2                  |output                          |
// +-----+--------------------+--------------------------------+
// |g3,g4|[D2,D3,D1, D2,D5,D1]|[[D2, D5, D1, D3], [2, 1, 2, 1]]|
// +-----+--------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.It helps in my scenario.If i want to print the 1st element of the output column how to do that if we use [ ].

Comment: If the DataFrame is small, your can use `collect` like `df2.select($"output"(0)).collect.foreach(println)` to print all rows of `output(0)`.  Replace `collect` with, say, `take(N)` to print just the first N rows in case the DataFrame is large.